# Is there a way to modify how webRTC works so to not leak my IP? (tfor example through plugins in the browser?)

Tags: firefox-extensions, plugins, chromium, browser-plugin, webrtc

question is in the headline - I just want to webRTC not leaking my IP, but I still have to use it. Is there any way through plugins - I have installed and tested a few, but I can't wrap my mind around them - to suppress webRTC leaking my address without deactivating it?

Best, Bogotrax

Comment: What do you consider "leaking". Your IP address must be known by any site you connect to, or it can't communicate with you.

Comment: "What is a WebRTC leak?

A WebRTC leak is when your external (public) IP address is exposed via your browser’s WebRTC functionality. This leak can de-anonymize you via WebRTC APIs, even if your VPN is working correctly.
If you have not protected yourself against WebRTC leaks in your browser, any website you visit could obtain your real (ISP-assigned) IP address through WebRTC STUN requests. [...]
While the WebRTC feature may be useful for some users, it poses a threat to those [...] seeking to maintain their online privacy[...] "[link](https://restoreprivacy.com/webrtc-leaks/)